# Using derivatives to find antiderivatives

Tags: calculus

Just to be up front this is a homework question, this is part c and im sure i've done parts A and B correctly.

[image]

I know how to use integration by parts to just take the indefinite integral of x cosx but im not sure how or why the derivative for x sinx is supposed to be useful. Can anyone help me see what im supposed to do here?

My derivative is $\sin(x)+x\cdot\cos(x)$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} [x\sin x] = \sin x + x\cos x$. By the FTC, the LHS is easy to integrate, as is $\sin x$. Hence, $x\cos x$ should be easy to integrate as well. Integration by parts is just what you get when you integrate the product rule, so there's nothing too deep going on here.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, ok thank you, I guess i was looking for a "ah-ha" moment but its just what it is

Comment: I should say, though, don't underrate the importance of this trick. The product rule gives you an algorithm for doing things like this, but sometimes making a clever choice of function and differentiating it is a good way to calculate an antiderivative. In particular, this sort of thing is contest math fodder.

Answer (score 2):

Since, $\frac{d}{dx}(x\sin x)\tag{1}=\sin x+x\cos x$, and the question asked us to use this

$$x\cos x=\color{green}{\sin x}+x\cos x -\color{green}{\sin x}$$

$$\int x\cos xdx=\int (\sin x+x\cos x -\sin x)dx$$
$$=\int (\sin x+x\cos x) dx - \int \sin x dx\tag{using eq.(1)}$$
$$=x\sin x +\cos x+C$$

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$(x\sin x)'=\sin x+x\cos x$$

Integrate both sides:
$$x\sin x+C=-\cos x+\int x\cos x \,dx$$

Then:
$$\int x\cos x \,dx=x\sin x+\cos x+C$$